# Hide XHR calls on Cypress test runner

Tags: cypress

I am trying to hide XHR calls on cypress test runner. I have added the following code in my `support/index.js` but it still doesn't work.

```js
Cypress.Server.defaults({
  delay:500,
  force404:false,
  ignore: (xhr) => {
    return false;
  },
})
```

Could anyone please suggest how it works?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this, works for me

Add the following to cypress/support/index.js:

```
// Hide fetch/XHR requests
const app = window.top;
if (!app.document.head.querySelector('[data-hide-command-log-request]')) {
  const style = app.document.createElement('style');
  style.innerHTML =
    '.command-name-request, .command-name-xhr { display: none }';
  style.setAttribute('data-hide-command-log-request', '');

  app.document.head.appendChild(style);
}
```

Referred and obtained details https://gist.github.com/simenbrekken/3d2248f9e50c1143bf9dbe02e67f5399

Comment: this works like a charm with Cypress v12.2 - Thanks a ton @Niluka Monnankulama

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was a pain seeing all this queries in the test runner 
I'm very thankful to you
the suite test run very quickly thanks to this, and we have less noise in the list

Comment: at least add the source https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/7362#issuecomment-944273204

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `Cypress.Server` is deprecated along with `cy.server()` (possibly it's the same thing).

An intercept might do what you want

```js
cy.intercept(url, (req) => {
  if (req.type === 'xhr') {
    // custom logic for handling
  }
})
```

But I don't think the example code you used was intended to "hide" the xhr requests. What is it you want to do with them?

Comment: I am trying to hide the xhr calls on cypress test runner.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this command:

```
Cypress.Server.defaults({
   
        ignore: (xhr) => bool   
})
```

**Note**: At least is working for the 9.7.0 Cypress version

Comment: Where to put this?

Answer (score 0):

To hide logs only in UI mode, not in headless, I added this function in a helper file:

```
const filterLogs = () => {
        const isUiMode = Cypress.config('isInteractive');
        if (isUiMode) {
            const filteredLogTypes = ['fetch', 'xhr'];
            const origLog = Cypress.log;
            Cypress.log = function (opts, ...other) {
                if (filteredLogTypes.includes(opts.displayName)) {
                    return;
                }
                return origLog(opts, ...other);
            };
        }
    };
```

Inside your support/e2e.js file:

```
filterLogs()
```

Props to the original writer, I got it from this page:
https://gist.github.com/simenbrekken/3d2248f9e50c1143bf9dbe02e67f5399?permalink_comment_id=4162440#gistcomment-4162440

opts.diplayName can be changed to whatever log you wanna hide.
Other opts values can also be checked, for example:
opts.url.startsWith("https://test.com") to hide logs from test.com.

Good luck!